# How to Modify the function to push the given item onto the end of the array and return the array

Tags: javascript

Modify the function to push the given item onto the end of the array and return the array.

```js
function addItemToArray(array, item) {

}

/* Do not modify code below this line */

const items = addItemToArray([1, 2, 3], 4);
console.log(items, '<-- should equal [1, 2, 3, 4]');
```

I tried to return Items but I received an error.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've modified `addItemToArray` yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just push the item into the array and return the array from the function :)

```js
function addItemToArray(array, item) {
    // .push() will add item to the end of the array
    array.push(item);
    return array;
}

/* Do not modify code below this line */

const items = addItemToArray([1, 2, 3], 4);
console.log(items, '<-- should equal [1, 2, 3, 4]');
```